# ALSA --- remarkably horrible sound output on headphones

Tags: arch-linux, audio, alsa, alsamixer

OS: Arch Linux (`4.13.12-1-ARCH`)

First of all, I'm **not** using `pulseadio`. I know it causes a lot of problems, but I'm just with `alsa`

### Situation

I have a 2.1 speaker system, plugged into the back panel of my PC. It works really nice, just as expected. The problem arises because sometimes I would like to use my headphones (since they're equipped with a mic) instead. I'd like to plug it into the front panel for convenience and quickly mute the speakers ('Front') in `alsamixer` and unmute 'Headphones'.

The problem is that sound coming from the headphones is just **terrible**. For example, consider this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=okpg-lVWLbE : this plays fine on my speakers, but on my headphones (when plugged into the front), I only hear the background music. The speech is just some weird noise, crackling. I've also tried media without background music: there, it just sounds like as people were speaking from the bottom of the sea...

### Some things I've noticed

- *Speakers* plugged into *back* panel --> sound is *fine*
- *Speakers* plugged into *front* panel --> sound is *fine*
- *Headphones* plugged into *back* panel --> sound is *fine*
- *Headphones* plugged into *front* panel --> sound is **horrible**
- I don't know if it's related, but in `chromium`, if I for example play the video and I switch to another tab, the audio starts lagging and crackling, *regardless of the output device*. This does not happen in `vlc` or `spotify` though. When I was using `pulseaudio`, I had no such problem.
- Sometimes an audible click is head when I start playing audio from a different source, e.g. I stop listening to music on `spotify` and start playing a video in `chromium`

### Info

Output of `aplay -l`

```
bertalanp99@watermelon > aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC892 Digital [ALC892 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

As requested, [THIS](https://pastebin.com/eafkfAhj) is the output of `amixer -c`

**Help would be greatly appreciated** :/

Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe hardware problem with your jack

Comment: Check the hardware mixer settings of your ALC892 with `alsamixer` (select correct card). The number one reason for "horrible sound" is wrong mixer settings. Number two would be hardware problems.

Comment: The number three reason for "horrible sound" is pulse-audio. You really only need pulseaudio if: 1. You want to use AirPlay speakers or 2. You have a system used by more than one person at the same time and each require their own sound.

Comment: @dirkt @thecarpy look, I updated my question entirely. I removed `pulseaudio`, but I'm still cursed

Comment: Pulseaudio is now mature enough to not cause "crackling" and lagging. If your headphones work fine in the back panel, but not in the front panel, that means Pulseaudio and ALSA can't be at fault, because they are doing exactly the same thing. I still suspect either (1) wrong mixer settings, or (2) a hardware defect. If you don't understand the `alsamixer` settings, please put the output of `amixer -c1` into a pastebin etc., and edit question with link.

Comment: @dirkt I got rid of `pulseaudio`. I really don't need it, do I? I think I know how `alsamixer` works, but I added what you requested to the question. I am not sure about hardware defect... Speaker works with front plug, so plug should be fine. Headphones work with back plug, so headphones are fine...

Comment: No, you don't need Pulseaudio, but it's also not the reason for the problem. The mixer settings look good. Speakers and Headphones have different impedance, so it still can be a hardware problem. Do the front and backpanels have different jacks for output and input (mic)? Does your headphone have a two jacks, one for the mic and one for the phones proper, or a combined jack?

Comment: @dirkt I think they have different jacks, yeah. My headphone has... Well, both... It's like it has a combined jack, but I have an extender cable sort of thing that has a mother end into which I plug the combined jack and the father end has two separate jacks, one for mic and one for sound. But I tried removing the extender cable and trying that way; didn't work

Comment: One way to narrow down the problem, e.g. that it's that particular headphone/front jack combination that causes trouble, would be to plug in other stuff in the front jack (and the back jack, for comparison), and see what happens. Maybe you can borrow some other headphones/speakers from friends?

Comment: @dirkt Holy cow, that was a good idea. It led me to discover something which I guess must be important! I plugged a pair of earphones (those small things) into the *front* slot and tested just as I did with the headphone. But when I unmuted the 'Headphones' in mixer, I accidentally pressed the `.` or `,` key, which only unmuted one channel. And sound got right! I could hear everything just as supposed to. I tried toggling only the other channel: same result. When I toggle both with `m`, I'm still getting the inaudible speech effect.  The same happens with the headphones!

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comment about muting left or right channel:

The combined jacks (headphone + mic), and also the headphone jacks have several rings, which are assigned to ground, left, right and mic. There are [several different standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_%28audio%29#TRRS_standards).

If somewhere, either in the extender cable and/or in the front jack, these assignments are mixed up because of an error during assembly, or if they use differing standards, you may get effects that lead to the crackling.

If you have an multimeter, measure the impedance between each two of the rings, this should allow you to figure out the assignments.

The 2.1 speaker system probably has amplification, which is why it doesn't show this effect.

Comment: I don't have a multimeter at home, but I can borrow one, so maybe I'll do that. But there's something else: I'm dual booting Windows 10 with Arch Linux. On Windows, the headphones work using both the front and back panels...